# jquery generated from custom control not working after postback

Tags: jquery, controls, postback, generated

I am creating a custom control to generate jQuery validation scripts for controls whose validation rules are dependant on configuration and therefore frequently changing. One of the requirements is that the validation must be done on the client side due to huge postbacks and latent, low bandwidth networks. An example of the output for my custom control is given below. I am having the common problem in that the jquery stops working after a postback and I've tried using PageLoad, Sys.Application.... etc but it's still a problem. I'm new to jQuery (JS in general) and wondering if generating lots of declarations of PageLoad when there should probably just be one is the issue? I can't hardcode any of the script because of the dynamic validation rules for each control.

```
        output.WriteLine("<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                        "$(document).ready(" +

                        "function () {" +
                        "  $('#" + ControlToValidate + "').mouseenter(function () {" +
                        "      $('#validate_msg_" + ControlToValidate + "').text('some error');" + 
                        "  });" +

                        "});" +
                        "</script>");

        output.WriteLine("<div id='validate_msg_" + ControlToValidate + "' style='color:Red'></div");
```

thanks very much for any help you can give!

Comment: is it a .net application?

Comment: yes the code I have given is inside a ASP.NET custom control, which takes a parameter of another control (like a CustomValidator) and the generates jQuery script to output to the page based in certain validation rules

Comment: if I use PageLoad only the last instance in the page will work

Answer (score 0):

adding to both the following maps solve the problem, The first is called after the initial load and the second following each AJAX call.

> $(document).ready(validatefunction);
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(validateFunction);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<asp:scriptmanager>` and programatically load the script file(put your jscript to a file) on every pageload.